# Возвратность и залог

Tags: возвратность

Немного запуталась.
Если у глагола есть постфикс "ся", он будет считаться возвратным даже в том случае, если выражает страдательное или безличное значения или нет?
Например:

> Берег **омывается** четырьмя морями. На улице **смеркается**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

См. «Справочник лингвистических терминов» Розенталя:

> **возвратный глагол**
>
> Глагол с аффиксом -*ся* (-*сь*). Объем понятия “возвратный глагол” и соотносительного с ним понятия “возвратная форма глагола” по-разному представлен в теоретических исследованиях и в учебной литературе.
>
> **В одних работах (“Морфология современного русского языка” И. Г. Голанова, школьные учебники) возвратными глаголами называются все глаголы с аффиксом (частицей, суффиксом) -*ся* независимо от их происхождения и залогового значения: сюда отнесены образования от переходных глаголов (*умываться, огорчаться, обниматься* и т. д., где -*ся* рассматривается как формообразующий аффикс), от непереходных глаголов (*плакаться, разгуляться, проснуться, пройтись* и т. д., где -*ся* является словообразующим аффиксом) и глаголы, которые без -*ся* не употребляются (*бояться, гордиться, карабкаться, надеяться, очнуться, смеяться, толпиться* и т. д.)**.
>
> В других работах (академическая “Грамматика русского языка”) возвратные глаголы — это глаголы возвратного залога, в отличие от которых глаголы с аффиксом -*ся*, не выражающие залогового значения, названы возвратными формами глагола; к последним отнесены образования от непереходных глаголов (*грозиться, звониться, стучаться* и т. д.) и глаголы, не употребляющиеся без -*ся* (см. выше).
>
> В третьих работах (университетский учебник “Современный русский язык”, ч. II) возвратными глаголами считаются самостоятельные лексические образования, в которых аффикс -*ся* выполняет словообразовательную функцию (*возиться, раздаться, прислоняться, перекликаться, прибраться, пораниться, плакаться, стучаться* и т. д., *гордиться, надеяться, смеяться* и т. д.), а возвратными формами глагола — образования, в которых аффикс -*ся* выполняет формообразующую функцию: это формы страдательного залога, сохраняющие лексико-семантическое тождество с переходными глаголами (*окно моется рабочим, улицы озеленяются комсомольцами* и т. д.). Различие в толковании терминов “возвратный глагол” и “возвратная форма глагола” связано с различным пониманием категории залога…
>
> *Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976.*

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/198/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

---

**P. S.**

Обратите внимание на этот фрагмент из приведённой выше статьи из справочника:

**В школьных учебниках** «возвратными глаголами называются **все глаголы с аффиксом (частицей, суффиксом) -*ся*** независимо от их происхождения и залогового значения…»

То же говорится и у Литневской в *«Кратком теоретическом курсе для школьников»*:

> **Возвратность в школьных учебниках определяется по наличию у глагола постфикса -*ся* (-*сь*). Это означает, что у спрягаемых форм глагола не определяется такой морфологический признак, как залог**, и формы страдательного залога спрягаемых форм типа *Дом строится рабочими* считаются отдельными возвратными глаголами. В данном случае в соответствии со школьной грамматикой имеем дело с глаголом *строиться*.
>
> https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/russkij-yazyk-kratkij-teoreticheskij-kurs-dlya-shkolnikov-4/morfologicheskiy-razbor-spryagaemykh-form-glagola-i-infinitiva

Answer (score 2):

1. *Берег **омывается** четырьмя морями. Четыре моря **омывают** берег.*

Двусоставные предложения, **активный и пассивный** (действительный и страдательный)  залог. Частица СЯ является показателем **пассивного** залога. Активный и пассивный залоги имеют только **личные переходные** глаголы (безличные и непереходные глаголы стоят **вне залога**).

**ОМЫТЬ,** -мою, -моешь; св. кого-что. Высок. =Обмыть (1 зн.); смыть. О. кровавые раны кому-л. О. лицо святой водой. О. покойника (вымыть тело покойного перед погребением). / О дожде, росе, струях воды. Цветы омыты росой. [] **безл.** Улицы **омыло** дождём. Омывать (см.). **Омываться**, -ается; **страд.**

**ОМЫВАТЬ,** -аю, -аешь; нсв. кого-что. 1. к Омыть. 2. Обдавать со всех сторон (водными струями). Волны омывают подножие горы. 3. **Окружать своими водами** (о морях, течениях и т.п.). Холодные течения **омывают** Сахалин. Воды Чёрного моря **омывают** город с юга.

2. *На улице **смеркается**.*

Большой толковый словарь

**СМЕРКНУТЬСЯ,** -нется; смерклось и смеркнулось, смерклась, смерклось; св. 1. Покрыться мраком, потемнеть; померкнуть. Кругом всё смерклось. День смеркся. 2. **безл.** О наступлении сумерек, вечерней темноты; стемнеть, стемнеться. Рано смерклось. Смеркаться, -ается; нсв.

Безличный непереходный глагол "смеркаться". Используется в **безличных** предложениях **глагольного** типа.

**[Синтаксис современного языка, стр.90](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**

```
  Там возможны варианты:
  1) безличный глагол: Вечереет; Светает;
  2) личный глагол в безличном значении (и безличной форме):
  В форточку дует; В ушах звенит; Лодку унесло течением;
  3) безлично-возвратный дериват личного глагола: Хочется 
  сока; В такое верится с трудом; Не спится.
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ИЗ КОММЕНТАРИЯ**

По словарю видно, что омыть/омывать – переходный и невозвратный глагол. Омываться – страдательный залог, частица СЯ является его показателем. Но я думаю, что в школе используется **УПРОЩЕННЫЙ вариант разбора.**

Залог не указывается, а все глаголы с частицей СЯ считаются **ВОЗВРАТНЫМИ.** Различить залоговое и возвратное значение бывает сложно, а по большому счету и не очень нужно. –

**Грамматическая справка**

**ВОЗВРАТНОСТЬ ГЛАГОЛА**

Возвратность глагола выражается с помощью частицы (или постфикса) СЯ, например: строить – невозвратный глагол, строиться – возвратный глагол.
Возвратные глаголы всегда являются непереходными.

```
  – Почему в русском языке не изучается пассивный залог, 
  известный в других языках? Его нет, или он для нас просто 
  неважен? 
 – Оказывается, пассивный залог существует, но как-то 
  «проходит мимо нас».
```

Итак, частица СЯ может являться: (1) показателем **пассивного** залога, который противопоставляется **активному залогу;** (2) показателем **возвратного** залога.

(1) **АКТИВНЫЙ И ПАССИВНЫЙ ЗАЛОГ**
Одна и та же ситуация, в которой участвуют субъект и прямой объект, описывается двумя способами, а именно: активный оборот: рабочие строят дом; пассивный оборот: дом строится рабочими.
Активный и пассивный залоги имеют только **личные переходные глаголы** (безличные и непереходные глаголы стоят вне залога).

(2) **ВОЗВРАТНЫЙ ЗАЛОГ**
В этом случае субъект совершает **активное** действие, направленное на себя, **прямой объект** при этом отсутствует.

**Частные** значения возвратности выражают следующие действия:

**СОБСТВЕННО ВОЗВРАТНОЕ** (субъект действия одновременно является объектом действия): умывать – умываться, одевать – одеваться;

**ВЗАИМНО-ВОЗВРАТНОЕ** (действие совершается несколькими субъектами, они же и объекты действия): целоваться, обниматься, судиться, ссориться, бороться;

**БЕЗОБЪЕКТНО-ВОЗВРАТНОЕ** (действие или состояние **характерно** для данного субъекта): собака кусается, крапива жжётся;

**ОБЩЕВОЗВРАТНОЕ** (действие совершается в самом субъекте; глаголы обозначают психическое или физическое состояние субъекта): сердиться, радоваться, удивляться, торопиться, стараться, надеяться, останавливаться, кланяться, пениться;

**КОСВЕННО-ВОЗВРАТНОЕ** (действие совершается субъектом для себя, в своих интересах): построиться (построить дом), прибраться, запастись;
В том числе **безличное** значение: ***хочется, не лежится, работается, достаётся.***

Comment: То есть, например, в первом примере, представлена невозвратный глагол, а форма страдательного залога?

Comment: По словарю видно, что омыть/омывать – переходный и невозвратный глагол. Омываться – страдательный залог, частица СЯ является его показателем. Но я думаю, что в школе используется упрощенный вариант разбора. Залог не указывается, а все глаголы с частицей СЯ считаются возвратными.  Различить залоговое и возвратное значение бывает сложно,  а по большому счету и не очень нужно.

Comment: А у всех безличных глаголов не принято определять залог?

Comment: Безличный глаголы непереходные,  то есть не могут иметь прямой объект. А значит, страдательного залога  не может быть.   Они стоят вне залога. Но есть безличные глаголы без частицы СЯ (вечереет, светает).  Они тоже вне залога.  Залоговое значение только у переходных глаголов.

Comment: Тема страдательного залога в русском языке  обозначена еще в страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени, которые образуются от переходных глаголов совершенного вида (нарисовать – нарисованный, перекинуть – перекинутый).  (Иногда от глаголов несов. вида.)  Но переходность там как обязательный признак.

Comment: Вот пример.  Строить  —  ПЕРЕХОДНЫЙ глагол.  (1) Рабочие строят дом. — Дом строится рабочими.  Страдательный ЗАЛОГ проявлен при наличии субъекта действия в форме дополнения (Т.п.).  (2) Дома быстро строятся. Страдательный залог не проявлен, это возвратный залог (общевозвратное значение).

Comment: При изучении глаголов мы не много внимания уделяем страдательному залогу, но очень внимательно отслеживаем переходность. Глагол непереходный?  Тогда он вне залога. Глагол имеет частицу СЯ? Тогда он непереходный и, соответственно, вне залога тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ

1. Для глагола залог является **НЕПОСТОЯННЫМ признаком** и при разборе **не называется**. Действительный или страдательный залог определяется **для переходных глаголов** и зависит от того, что именно является в предложении **подлежащим** (объект действия или субъект действия).

Соответственно, в школе указывается залог только при разборе **причастий**, для них это **постоянный** признак.

2. В школе **омывается** и ***смеркается*** называют **возвратными** глаголами по частице ***СЯ***, но подробно залог не рассматривается. В действительности это разные залоги: **страдательный** залог у глагола ***омывается*** и **возвратный** залог у безличного залога ***смеркается***.