Двучленная конструкция
Как определять залог в двучленной конструкции, в которой отсутствует указание на деятеля в творительном падеже?

Фильм транслируется по телевизору.

Если деятель не назван, то это значит, что перед нами действительный залог? Если залог все же страдательный, то как это можно понять по двучленной конструкции? Может ли данная конструкция называть возвратный глагол в действительном залоге, который равен по значению фразе "может транслироваться по телевизору"?

Ответ на вопрос

Будем исходить из того, что залог у русских глаголов все же есть.  В общем случае существуют три залога: действительный, страдательный и средневозвратный. Нам нужно определить залог глагола транслироваться в конкретном предложении: Фильм транслируется по телевизору.

Итак, частица СЯ может являться: (1) показателем страдательного залога, который противопоставляется действительному залогу; (2) показателем возвратного залога. Действительный и страдательный  залоги имеют только личные переходные глаголы (безличные и непереходные глаголы стоят вне залога). Для конкретного существительного наличие страдательного залога уточняется по словарю.

Частица СЯ — морфологический показатель залога, но есть еще синтаксический показатель. Из статьи по теме:


Важнейшим грамматическим показателем страдательного залога является творительный падеж существительного со значением деятеля, реального субъекта действия. Отсутствие такого творительного падежа сближает страдательное значение глагола со средневозвратным, особенно в том случае, когда подлежащим является название лица (ср.: Туристы отправляются в поход – Письма отправляются по почте).
Синтаксическими средствами выражения залоговых значений являются: а) синтаксическое различие в выражении субъекта и объекта действия (ср.: Вода размывает берег – Берег размывается водой); б) наличие объекта действия и полное отсутствие его (ср.:Дождь повышает урожай – Дождь начинается); в) различие форм и значения существительных, управляемых глаголом (ср.: Договор заключается фирмой – Договор заключается с фирмой).

Из предыдущего текста можно сделать вывод о важности контекста. Значение глагола в заданном предложении может быть разным: в данный момент идет трансляция, фильм разрешен для трансляции и т.д.

Но в любом случае по отсутствию  существительного в Т.п. делается вывод о том, что это возвратный, а не страдательный залог. Конкретно —  собственно-возвратное значение (субъект действия одновременно является объектом действия): транслировать — транслироваться.
В то ж время по семантике граница между этими вариантами условная, как в предложениях: Договор заключается фирмой (страд.)  — Договор заключается с фирмой (возвр.)
Сравнить: Фильм транслируется по телевизору (возвр.). - Фильм транслируется федеральным каналом (страд.).
Карта слов
Пример страдательного залога
Если оставить всё как есть в отношениях, то велика вероятность, что похожая модель поведения будет транслироваться дочерью уже на собственных детях, делая их тоже несчастными, передавая травматический опыт по наследству. Татьяна Якубовская, 2023

Теперь понятно. Спасибо

Это пока не ответ, а размышление на тему: Есть ли залог у русских глаголов?

Как известно, в русском языке глагол находится вне залога. Вернее, это известно школьникам в соответствии с учебником Литневской, где утверждается следующее: В предложении "Дом строится рабочими" нет страдательного залога, но есть возвратный залог. С каким значением? Ну, вероятно, со страдательным, но об этом не сказано.
Вопрос о значении возвратных глаголов затронут только в 
комплексе 2, где среди указанных значений описано 
«страдательное значение»: дом строится каменщиками. В 
лингвистике конструкции такого рода чаще описывают как 
личную форму страдательного залога. Глагол стоит в форме 
страдательного залога в том случае, если в позиции 
подлежащего при нём находится существительное со 
значением объекта, а не субъекта действия. Однако во всех 
трех учебных комплексах морфологический признак залога 
выделяется только у причастий, поэтому согласно школьной 
грамматике любой глагол с -ся представляет собой 
самостоятельное слово.

Возвратность в школьных учебниках определяется по наличию 
у глагола постфикса -ся (-сь). Это означает, что у 
спрягаемых форм глагола не определяется такой 
морфологический признак, как залог, и формы 
страдательного залога спрягаемых форм типа Дом строится 
рабочими считаются отдельными возвратными глаголами. В 
данном случае в соответствии со школьной грамматикой 
имеем дело с глаголом строиться.



А это для продвинутых школьников из школы Фоксфорд:
Что такое залог глагола
Залог глагола – непостоянный признак этой части речи, 
зависящий от того, что является в предложении подлежащим. 
Если подлежащее – совершающий действие субъект, то залог 
глагола будет действительным. А если подлежащее – объект, на 
который действие направлено, и есть дополнение в 
творительном падеже, обозначающее действующий субъект, то 
глагол нужно использовать в форме страдательного залога.

Важно отличать форму страдательного залога от возвратного 
глагола. Если в предложении есть только субъект и действие 
направлено на него самого, то глагол является возвратным.


Сейчас  в школах возможно  нет или не будет учебных комплексов, но с 7-го класса начинается специализация по направлениям. Возможно, школьники общеобразовательного направления должны считать, что залога у глагола нет, а в филологических классах будут считать, что он, напротив, есть. Чем составителям программ не угодил залог, трудно сказать.

Дело в том, что он реально существует, и это видно по словарям.


Представьте себе такое объявление «Внимание! Хищники кормятся исключительно работниками зоопарка!»  Забавно! Но оно не совсем корректно, так как  в словаре указано значение глагола кормиться, и залог там явно возвратный, но не страдательный.
   КОРМИТЬСЯ, кормлюсь, кормишься; нсв. 1. Есть, питаться, 
   получать, добывать пищу. Выгнать лошадей к. в поле ночью. 
   Приходится к. только тем, что добываем охотой. 2. (св. 
   прокормиться). Содержать себя, добывать средства к 
   пропитанию, к жизни. К. своим трудом. К. каким-л. 
   промыслом. К. от земли. Кормёжка (см.).

Может, страдательный залог вообще не указывается, но нет. Посмотрим другое слово:
   ТРАНСЛИРОВАТЬ, -рую, -руешь; св. и нсв. что. Передать - 
   передавать что-л. по радио или телевидению 
   непосредственно с места действия, в прямом эфире. Т. 
   заседание съезда. Т. праздничный концерт. Т. футбольный 
   матч. Транслироваться, -руется; СТРАД. Трансляция (см.).

Да уж, нечего сказать! Залога у глагола нет, но он все-таки есть. Поэтому сначала надо решить этот вопрос, а затем уже обсуждать тему.
Примечание. Вопрос обсуждался на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478649/Возвратность-и-залог  Там был принят ответ с цитатами из Литневской и Справочника 1976 года.

В одном из словарей говорится, что у "транслировать" страдательный залог.

О чем и речь. Но вот вы  предыдущей теме согласились, что залога нет. Так как тогда обсуждать вашу новую тему?

Кстати, насчет фразы  с "кормятся". Ее же можно двояко трактовать. Хищники кормят себя работниками. Работники кормят хищников.

В "кормиться" нет залога, не указан в словаре.

Эта похожая тема, но все-таки не такая же. Дело здесь в залоге. Если мы рассматриваем школьную норму, то там все глаголы с "ся" возвратными считаются. Мне важно понять, каков здесь залог и почему.

Почему нет? кормиться несов.


Есть, питаться. // Добывать пищу.


Содержать себя. // Добывать средства к жизни.


Страд. к глаг.: кормить.



Вам важно для себя или для школы? В той теме вам даже ответа не предложили, а только эти цитаты, и вы согласились.

Для школы нужно, конечно.

Вы используете Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь. У Кузнецова указания о страдательности нет. Так как же учится, по каким программам? Признает ваша школа залог или нет?
